# how to use props inside styled-component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I want to pass a url to a component then use this url to set the background image of the component.
also i want to check if a url is empty .

component :

```
<BannerImg/>

css (styled) : 
`const BannerImg = styled.img`
background-image: url( // any url...);
z-index:9;
position:relative;
`
```

while searching , i found something like (though it was not clear at all ) and interpreted as :

```
interface Props{
  url :string
}

const BannerImg=styled.img<Props>`
  background-image:url (${p=> p.url});
`
```

component :

`<BannerImg url={imageurl}/>`

but this is throwing me error in the url of the component

error:

`o overload matches this call. Overload 1 of 2, '(props: { title?: string | undefined; slot?: string | undefined; style?: CSSProperties | undefined; ref?: ((instance: HTMLImageElement | null) => void) | RefObject<...> | null | undefined; ... 277 more ...; url: string; } & { ...; } & { ...; }): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error. Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'. Overload 2 of 2, '(props: StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"img", any, Props, never, "img", "img">): ReactElement<StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"img", any, Props, never, "img", "img">, string | JSXElementConstructor<...>>', gave the following error. Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2769) AesthCard.tsx(12, 3): The expected type comes from property 'url' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { title?: string | undefined; slot?: string | undefined; style?: CSSProperties | undefined; ref?: ((instance: HTMLImageElement | null) => void) | RefObject<...> | null | undefined; ... 277 more ...; url: string; } & { ...; } & { ...; }' AesthCard.tsx(12, 3): The expected type comes from property 'url' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { title?: string | undefined; slot?: string | undefined; style?: CSSProperties | undefined; ref?: ((instance: HTMLImageElement | null) => void) | RefObject<...> | null | undefined; ... 277 more ...; url: string; } & { ...; } & { ...; }`

Answer (score 0):

I made the url prop optional in the Props interface, as it seems you want to be able to handle cases where the URL is not provided.
I used the template literal for the background-image property in the styled component, and I added a default image URL (replace 'defaultImageUrl' with the actual default URL you want to use) in case the url prop is undefined.
This should resolve the TypeScript error you're encountering. Make sure that the imageUrl you are passing to BannerImg is indeed a string and not undefined. If it can be undefined, make sure to handle that case appropriately in your application logic.